# Why did Avraham pray for a son if he was promised one?

Tags: tefilla, abraham, genesis-bereishith, avodath-hashem

Hashem promised Avraham as son when he left Haran, at age 75. Yet it seems that Avraham and Sarah prayed for the next 25 years until they indeed were blessed with Yitzhak.

How could we describe Avraham's reason for tefilla, if seemingly not asking to *take* from Hashem. (Perhaps related to abundantly eager to *give* to Hashem... but I feel there is more to it.)

Comment: To speed up the delivery of the promise?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi What's the rush? His ratzon to serve Hashem?

Comment: Have you ever anxiously waited for a baby to announce himself?

Comment: A major premise of this question is that they prayed. Citing a source for that claim would improve the question drastically.

Comment: @msh210 I was assuming that the same way Yitzhak prayed tremendously for Yaakov, Avraham did so for Yitzhak. So perhaps we can ask on Yitzhak (https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.21), as Avraham was promised to become a great, lasting nation (https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.2) specifically from Yitzhak (https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.2).